# Why Google compute engine autoscaling creates too much instances when multi-zone is selected?

Tags: multiple-instances, autoscaling, google-compute-engine

I've been using autoscaling based on cpu usage. We used to set it up using a single zone, but to ensure instance availability we are now creating it with multi-zone enabled.

Now it seems to create much more instances than required according to cpu usage. I believe it has to do with the fact that instances are created among different zones and the total usage calculation somehow is not taking that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the regional autoscaler will need at least 3 instances that will be located in 3 different zones, even though your utilisation is lower and it could be served from an instance in a single zone. This is to provide resiliency, because a region is less likely to go down than a single zone.